# unable to connect to ubuntu 21.10 shared desktop

Tags: screen, vnc, 21.10, desktop-sharing

I have two physical machines with ubuntu 21.10 installed, machine 1 screen sharing works perfectly from machine 2 as client and windows machines (it took zero effort!).  machine 2 screen sharing is enabled, but nothing can connect to it (tight vnc viewer from windows, remmina from machine 1), ssh is working and I can connect via terminal, there appear to be nothing interesting in the logs to show anything is wrong?

Remmina shows the vnc password prompt with a "could not authenticate, attempting reconnection" banner, the password prompt is re-displayed, and around and around it goes!, there is no sign of rejection on the server and port 5900 is listening.
When Remmina is showing password prompt connection is shown as established.

tcp6       0      0 :::5900                 :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 192.x.x.x:5900        192.x.x.x:43928       ESTABLISHED

The established connection is shown on both sides (machine 1 and 2), so I suspect its the actual password validation that's going wrong, but this is on a clean build with no fiddling?

Are there any clues where I can start looking?  I have followed the vino route, but ubuntu 21.10 is not using vino, I have rebuilt machine 2 half a dozen times with the same end result.

The hardware is a Fujitsu Primergy TX100 S3 with two Intel Nic's only Nic 1 is being used.

The real shame is its machine 2 that I really want sharing to work from (its normally headless), it was running Windows.... I am lookig for some guidance to know where to go looking, or should I abandon ubuntu screen share and install a standalone vnc-server? at least the configuration will be in my face!

Comment: Are you running Wayland?

Answer (score 0):

Yes I am running Wayland... I now understand what my issue is...

I was stuck in a loop not understanding that when a display is disconnected then no screen is drawn and hence VNC cannot connect,  I have tinkered with virtual displays, but nothing is playing nicely, I have purchased a HDMI dummy plug, that should solve my issue, I hope :-)